# Elantra stereo adapter

Tags: audio

I own a 2006 Hyundai Elantra, and I just bought [this](http://www.crutchfield.com/S-Nu75x8D2VFV/p_105KDR520/JVC-KD-R520.html#accessories-tab) stereo. Upon installing it, learned that the hookup to my factory stereo is radically different from that of the new one.

don't really have any electrical experience, and have never done anything like this before, so I'd really rather not have to splice the adapter that came with the new stereo to fit the old one (presumably with something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KL128S). I'd really like to just buy an adapter that can bridge my car's hookup to the new stereo's port. Does anyone know of such a thing? The closes I've found is [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/CT20HY02-Hyundai-Accent-Coupe-Elantra-ISO-Stereo-Head-Unit-Harness-Adaptor-Lead-/160529684181?pt=UK_In_Car_Technology&hash=item25605096d5#ht_1402wt_1139), but looking at the picture, it doesn't look like it would fit into my new stereo.

Can somebody confirm that (maybe I'm just missing something?), and if so, could you recommend where to find a proper adapter, such that I can just plug one end into my new stereo and the other into the cable coming out of my car? I really hope such a thing exists...

Thank you.

Comment: Crutchfield (who you linked to) will often sell you the custom wiring harness / adapter required to make the stereo fit your car.  I'd recommend contacting them and pleading for mercy.

Answer (score 2):

The new stereo should come with a cable that plugs in the back and ends in a pair of ISO sockets. These should then mate to the adaptor you linked from ebay (the two small rectangular plugs on the right-hand side of that picture), which in turn should mate to the car's existing wiring harness.